Hard to read Chrome textboxes when OS has dark mode and theme


My Windows 10 has dark mode enabled
Visiting the website https://shopee.sg, it was not in dark mode, so I do expect the textbox to render in white
However, it renders in black text on a dark background making it really hard to read
Any ideas what config I might be missing?


As is often the case, I found the solution shortly after posting.

My MacOS Chrome did not have the issue, so I dug deeper
The issue is, I modified my Windows DLL using UXTheme Patcher
The fix was to install this Chrome extension User javascript and CSS https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld?hl=en
And added this CSS for the URL pattern *://*/*
input {
    background-color: #FFF
}



